# Problem with Grails and FilterPane after upgrade

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I just upgraded from grails 1.2.0 to 1.3.7 and to the latest version of the FilterPane Plugin.

Now I have an error where before was all right.

In my list.gsp I had/have

```
<div class="list">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <g:sortableColumn property="id" title='${message(code:"doi.doi.string")}' params="${filterParams}"/>

                        <g:sortableColumn property="url" title='${message(code:"doi.doi.url")}' params="${filterParams}"/>

                        <g:sortableColumn property="registrationDate" title='${message(code:"doi.doi.registration.date")}' params="${filterParams}"/>

                        <g:sortableColumn property="lastUpdateDate" title='${message(code:"doi.doi.last.update.date")}' params="${filterParams}"/>

                        <g:if test="${session.user.isAdmin}">
                            <g:sortableColumn property="owner" title='${message(code:"doi.doi.user")}' params="${filterParams}"/>
                        </g:if>                   
                    </tr>
                </thead>
```

...

And in the Controller I updated the filter action to

```
def filter =
{
    if(!session.user)
    {
        loadUser();
    }

    flash.args = [session.user.firstName, session.user.lastName];

    if(!params.max)
    {
        params.max = 20;
    }

    render( view:'list', model:[doiList: filterPaneService.filter(params, Doi), 
    doiCount: filterPaneService.count(params, Doi), 
    filterParams: org.grails.plugin.filterpane.FilterPaneUtils.extractFilterParams(params), 
    params:params])
}
```

as in the plugin page.

Now I get an error which says

```
 ERROR grails.app.tagLib.org.grails.plugin.filterpane.FilterPaneTagLib(org.apache.commons.logging.Log$error.call(?:?))  - domain attribute is required
```

and when I click on the link to open the Panel, nothing happens

Do I miss something that with the new version doesn't work anymore?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Francesco

Comment: No one has ever had such a problem?

Comment: Problem solved. I didn't notice the "There are several breaking changes when migrating to 2.0. Please take note!" :)